# When writing a Sherpa study, how do I address "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'" in my 'study.keras_callback' call?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization, keras, hyperparameters

I have built a neural network that executes successful using tensorflow and keras. Now I am trying to optimize hyperparameters using sherpa. This is my first time using sherpa and I am working through the documentation. I disabled the dashboard because that seemed to be the only way to go. Now, where I have gotten stuck is at the **'study.keras_callback'**. I am receiving **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'"**. The environment I am working in has tensorflow, keras installed. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

parameters = [sherpa.Discrete('num_units', [50, 200])]
alg = sherpa.algorithms.RandomSearch(max_num_trials=50)

study = sherpa.Study(parameters=parameters,
                     algorithm=alg, disable_dashboard=True,
                     lower_is_better=True)
for trial in study:
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],),
                           name='hidden_layer_1',),
        keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],),
                           name='hidden_layer_2',),
        keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],),
                           name='hidden_layer_3',),
        keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],),
                           name='hidden_layer_4',),
        keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],),
                           name='hidden_layer_5',),
        keras.layers.Dense(1, name='output_layer',)
    ])
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer = 'adam', metrics=['mae'])
    model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=200,verbose=0,
              callbacks=[study.keras_callback(trial, objective_name='val_loss')])
    study.finalize(trial)
```

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install keras separately. Do: pip install keras
hope this is gonna help

Comment: So, I have this written:

`import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras`
Is this not the same thing? Or do I need to do that as well? I should also probably mention I am writing this script in a Jupyter notebook and the environment I am running the kernel through has tensorflow, keras, sklearn, all installed already.

Comment: importing  tensorflow and keras from tensorflow acts only in your open notebook. while your sherpa core.py  (and its keras_callbacks fucntion that gives you this error ) looks for keras module in your installed modules. So what you need is to install keras directly from your terminal.